# How to modify permissions for scheduled tasks in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a scheduled task that I want to be able to run/trigger as a normal user that has no administrative privileges on the local computer. The task itself was created with the account `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`

When I run the task with PowerShell, it gives me `Start-ScheduledTask : Access is denied`

What I have done so far

Set `Allow` for `List folder contents` and `Read` on
`C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`

Set `Allow` for `Read & execute` and `Read` on
`C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\MyTask`

How can I modify permissions for `Authenticated Users` to be able to run/trigger MyTask?

Comment: By design, you cannot run a task using a group. It's always user context only. It does not matter how the task was created, any task can be modified to run with a different set of creds. You set that on the task directly, not at the file system.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have a task run as SYSTEM but be able to be triggered by any user? The user should not be able to modify the task.

Comment: You set whatever identity you choose on a given task. as for this `The user should not be able to modify the task`. Tasks are just text files. A user can just copy the task, change it and run it. Or look at a task's settings and just recreate it. Users don't have to open the task scheduler to modify/run a task. there is an executable for that. `schtasks.exe /?`. Yet as far as ST permissions (these are not controlled by PowerShell), [there are many articles on that topic](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27permissions+needed+for+task+scheduler%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: Lastly, unless the use is not a local admin, then the permission settings are moot; for as we know, local admin means full ownership of everything on the box. They can change whatever they choose to.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. I was hoping to find a solution where a normal user can execute certain tasks that requires administrative privileges.

Comment: Why does a user need to run this task? Can't you just it to run a specific time of the day on a targeted schedule? Your other option is to set a credential in the Windows credential manager, write a script to run the task with those creds. Create a shortcut a user clicks to run it.

Comment: The task basically runs a script that requires admin privileges, therefore I set it up to run as system. But at the same time it requires the user which it is intended for to be logged in. So it’s user context based. The scripts job is to create a VPN profile for the user but when it tries to this with just the user account I receive ”access denied”. The part where this happen I believe is where it deletes the old profile from VPNv2 CSP. I have been able to get around this though by copying a file named rasphone.pbk, so I did not end up using the task scheduler. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Slamdunk So you need the task for the same reason users need access to setuid programs in unix-based systems. Did you ever find a solution?